# Custom CSS reference in Page Layout

Tags: css, page-layout

I want to refer Custom CSS in my Page Layout

Page Layout

```
<link href="&#60;%$SPUrl:~sitecollection/Style Library/Test/Custom.css %&#62;" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" ms-design-css-conversion="no"  runat="server"/>
```

Page-> View Source Below

```
<link href="/sites/UAT/_catalogs/masterpage/&lt;%$SPUrl:~sitecollection/Style Library/Test/Custom.css %>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"></link>
```

Actual CSS

```
/sites/UAT/Style%20Library/Test/Custom.css
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Styles**

If your page layout is an HTML file, try this:

```
<!--SPM:<SharePoint:CssRegistration name="&#60;% $SPUrl:~sitecollection/Style Library/Test/Custom.css %&#62;" runat="server" after="corev15.css"/>-->
```

If it'is an .aspx file, try this:

```
<SharePoint:CssRegistration name="&#60;% $SPUrl:~sitecollection/Style Library/Test/Custom.css %&#62;" runat="server" after="corev15.css"/>
```

**Scripts**

HTML masterpage:

```
<!--SPM:<SharePoint:ScriptLink language="javascript" Name="~SiteCollection/Style Library/Test/Custom.js" runat="server" Localizable="false"/>-->
```

aspx masterpage:

```
<SharePoint:ScriptLink language="javascript" Name="~SiteCollection/Style Library/Test/Custom.js" runat="server" Localizable="false"/>
```

Comment: Can you please suggest way for Custom js file also

Comment: I updated the answer