# Custom Search Box Template not working properly

Tags: search, display-template

I have created Display Template for Search Box. It is working fine but some time it shows error message.

```
Sorry, something went wrong.
Display Error: The display template had an error. You can correct it by fixing the template or by changing the display template used in either the Web Part properties or Result Types.

Template '~sitecollection/_catalogs/masterpage/Display Templates/Search/SearchBox_Cust.js' not found or has syntax errors. (LoadTemplate: )
```

Comment: It would likely help if you posted your SearchBox_Cust.js code as well since this error doesn't give us much to go on, thanks!

Comment: @theChrisKent due to master page i was getting issue. thanks

Comment: Glad to hear your issue is resolved. Would you mind posting the solution as an answer to your own question? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Unnecessary link created for Custom css file in master page which causing issue in rendering search box.Use this approach [Custom CSS/Js link in Master page and Page Layout](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/204097/custom-css-reference-in-page-layout)  not below one

```
<link href="&lt;% $SPUrl:~sitecollection/Style Library/Test/Custom.css %&gt;" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" ms-design-css-conversion="no" runat="server" />
```